# UIAlertController crash for being presented in backgroundThread objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have been using `UIAlertController` in previous apps but I am facing a strange error this time. Here is my code which I using to present it:

```
     UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE_STRING message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
     [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:OK_STRING style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

     }]];
     [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{

     }];
```

Everything was fine but now I my app crashes on last line. Here is error:

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This
>   will cause an exception in a future release.

I am not using `autolayout` in my app. I have no idea why I am getting this error.

Any clues?

Comment: Why don't you try to present `alert` in the main thread?

Comment: The method which populates alert controller is called in background thread

Comment: But you can call `alert` in the main thread with `dispatch_asyn`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error is displayed when you try to do UI tasks in a background thread. Just change your code to this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:ALERT_TITLE_STRING message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
     [alertController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:OK_STRING style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

     }]];


        [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController] presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:^{
     }];
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem. I updated my architecture and called this method on main thread rather than making this change. I appreciate your effort :)

Answer (score 6):

You can't handle UI in any other thread than the main thread.

If you're currently in another thread, you can force a block of code to be executed on the main thread anyway, by putting it inside the following block.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Display your UIAlertController here
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not allowed to perform UI operations on any thread but the main thread. The alert controller will be using autolayout internally which is why you're seeing the error.

Use `dispatch_async`to present the alert from the main thread instead.